# PYTHONPATH problem in cron

Tags: cron, python, python3

I have been trying to automatically run a Python script with cron, to understand PATH.

First I try with the user crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

I set up crontab like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/dpa/anaconda3/bin/python
PATH=/home/dpa/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
36 15 * * * python /home/dpa/PycharmProjects/Parser/Parser.py >> /tmp/mycommand.log 2>&1
```

The script does not run, and I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: python: not found
```

---

Then I try as superuser:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and I set up cronetab like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/dpa/anaconda3/bin
PATH=/home/dpa/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin 
43 15 * * * su - dpa python /home/dpa/PycharmProjects/Parser/Parser.py >> /tmp/mycommand.log 2>&1
```

Now the STDERR looks like this:

```
-su: python: No such file or directory
```

Comment: why are you setting the python module search path `PYTHONPATH` to a executable or directory where executables go? executables are not modules.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did it because I found this guide: https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/calling-a-python-script-from-crontab/

Comment: Did you check the simple things (like `/home/dpa/anaconda3/bin/python` actually exists - and is not a broken link for example?)

Comment: @steeldriver, thanks for the input! I checked the path, and it did indeed exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, as you have `root` access, I would recommend you compile and build `anaconda` in `/opt` and not in your home directory.

What you are effectively doing is setting the variable PATH as being equal to that list of directories and PYTHONPATH as being equal to that one directory where the `anaconda` executables are which is causing your issue.

To get what you want, a better way is to become root and then, assuming your shell is `bash`:

```
export PATH=/home/dpa/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/dpa/anaconda3/lib
export PYTHONHOME=/home/dpa/anaconda3
bash
```

That sets the path and library to look in the directories containing anaconda python and its libraries and `bash` starts a new session. You can then add the `python` command to `crontab`.

If you are going to run it as `root` then you don't need the `su -` and it's also better just to run it in the `crontab` of `root` as the way you have it, `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` are set in your user's environment and not in that of `root`.

If it's better, you can put it all into a script and just add the script itself to `crontab`.

Once again, I recommend installing anaconda into `/opt` and not your user's home directory.

Comment: I ran the commands as you wrote, and for some reason it works now! I still need to learn more about this PATH/PYTHONPATH though. Do you have any good resources to start with?

Comment: @Program It's more to do with setting your path and exporting environment variables in general.  A simple Google search for "exporting bash variables" and "setting path in Linux" will help you. They all cover everything pretty well so you'll find what you need by going over them and working with them on your machine. To get you started, if it's more convenient, you can add the lines beginning with `export` to your `~/.bash_profile` and then `source ~/.bash_profile` as `root`. That will set it permanently so you won't have to do it every time.